# Client has asked for a piece to be rewritten after agency acceptance of my submission. How much should I charge?

Tags: websites

Yesterday I was given a job which was to proofread a website and make any changes "where necessary". That's all the brief said. I did so, amended any typos etc, changed some grammar and spiced it up here and there. I submitted my piece and my agency accepted it, meaning I get paid. Great.

I am a freelance copywriter. Today I get a message saying that the client says there was a "misunderstanding". He says he wants the text rewritten in a way that sells the site more, not just changed here and there. Clearly my agency thought I had fulfilled his brief, because they accepted my submission, but he is saying he wants the thing basically rewritten from scratch as I understand it.

How much do I charge for this revision? I will be paid X for my original submission. But should I charge X again, because this sounds like a new job, half of X or less? I love my agency and don't want to annoy them, but it seems that the client's original brief was really vague. I am unsure of what to do.

Comment: IMHO this belongs on https://freelancing.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, but I only posted here on the advice that I should do so, after originally posting this on Writing SE. I think I will just consult my agency. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, smells like trouble.
There may be more "misunderstandings", this time for free ;)

I would suggest to decline

Comment: Just as another follow-up, you were correct. I rewrote it for half the fee and the client still rejected it. You were very observant to see that trouble could be afoot. At least I got paid, but I don't only do this for the money, I do it because I love the craft and I want clients to be happy. It's sad if that doesn't happen.

Comment: Its always better to go in to the situation with open eyes. Even if you smell trouble you can be ready for them :)

Answer (score 3):

I will answer this for anyone who ends up in a similar situation. I consulted my agency and they were very nice and completely understood the issue at hand. We agreed at half the amount, everything is going ahead.

Answer (score -1):

Charge at least X what they are asking is for SEO optimisation - they would also need to tell you what keywords to target.

Comment: They've given a list of keywords, yes. I included those in the original submission, but maybe I should include them all a few more times. I don't want to annoy my agency but this is a lot of work to rewrite the whole thing, esp after yesterday when I spent time proofing and polishing it. Nevertheless I have been transparent with my agency. We have a very good relationship and I have asked them what they consider reasonable to do in these circumstances.